# How to retain value after going from one Actitivity to another and coming back to the previous actitivity?

Tags: android, android-intent, return-value, intentservice

So the working of my application is it has an activity called "Add Reminder" this activity has some textbox which the user can enter values in them then the user goes to the next activity by clicking a button which is a GoogleMaps and they can tap a location and get their Latitude and Longitude after tapping on the Marker the **Intent** stores the value of latitude and longitude.
When users click a button which is a tick icon then these values are being sent to the previous activity so the issue which I'm facing is when the user goes backs to the "Add Reminder" Activity. if the user types anything before going to the new GoogleMaps activity  and comes back the TextBox is empty as Android consider this as a new fresh activity is there a way to retain those values until the user comes from the GoogleMaps activity.

**Add Reminder Actitivity Intent**

```
startActivity(new Intent(AddReminderActivity.this,MapsActivity.class));
```

**GoogleMaps Actitivity Intent**

```
Intent data = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, AddReminderActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("lat", latitude.toString());
                    b.putString("lng", longitude.toString());
                    data.putExtra("personBdl", b);
                    startActivity(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing things wrong.  You shouldn't be returning to the AddReminder by launching an Intent.  You return by finish(), going back to the previous activity.  To return a value from the AddReminder activity, use startActivityForResult to start the MapsActivity, and set a result bundle before calling finish.

Comment: So how should i do that AddReminder -> Google Maps -> AddReminder ?

Comment: You launch Maps using startActivityForResult.  You return to AddReminder by using finish(0 (or the back button on the phone will automatically call finish).  You get the results from MapsActivity using onActivityResult.  See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you